# How to query date in mySQL with string data type

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get data from mySQL table within two dates. The data type of "date" column is string.  My mySQL query is

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE date between STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') and STR_TO_DATE('20/03/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')
```

It shows nothing. if I write,

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE date between '01/03/2017'  and '20/03/2017'
```

it takes almost all data. Here is the screen shot.

[image: Screen]

Comment: What is the data type of your date column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your 'date' data type is string then your query will use string comparison. You have to convert 'date' column to date data type too, STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y'),  if you want date comparison.

You could use something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `accounts` 
    WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d/%m/%Y') BETWEEN 
         STR_TO_DATE('01/03/2017', '%d/%m/%Y') AND
         STR_TO_DATE('20/03/2017', '%d/%m/%Y')
```